# Secure and deterministic browser symmetric key generation?

Tags: wallets, encryption, hardware-wallets

I would like to know, what are the best practices to solve the following problem:

Imagine there's an Alice with browser and Ethereum account (connected with Metamask / Wallet connect / etc). She needs to generate a symmetric key and encrypt text "Foo buzz" with it. The key and encryption algorithm must satisfy the following properties:

1. **Deterministic**. Alice may use another device with the same Ethereum account - and she must be able to generate the same key to decrypt the text.
2. **Secure**. Encrypted text is publicly available, which means that any weak-security solutions (hashing password to get an entropy) does not suit
3. **Wallet agnostic** Metamask has the `eth_decrypt` and `eth_getEncryptionPublicKey`  methods which are great, but this approach has it's own limitations:

   - Currently these methods are supported only by Metamask
   - Ledger (probably other hardware wallets) does not support them ([Github Ledger PR](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1422), no progress since 2021)
   - Some time ago they were marked as deprecated ([Metamask blog post](https://medium.com/metamask/metamask-api-method-deprecation-2b0564a84686))